# Reading and writing to txt files

Tags: java, file, if-statement, printwriter

I'm writing a code that reads in file Banking.txt and asks for userID & pin, then prompting the user to make a withdrawal, deposit, or check balance. The balance will be written to Records.txt. The program terminates after the user enters the pin, & i can't figure out how to make it continue. Please help

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File fil1 = new File("Banking.txt");
    File fil2 = new File("Records.txt");
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(fil1);
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(fil2);
    String fname;
    String mname;
    String lname;
    String uid = null;
    int pin = 0;
    double balance = 0;
    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(fil2); 
    while (sc1.hasNext()) {
        fname = sc1.next();
        mname = sc1.next();
        lname = sc1.next();
        uid = sc1.next();
        pin = sc1.nextInt();
        balance = sc1.nextDouble();
        BankRecord person = new BankRecord(fname,mname,lname,uid,pin,balance);
        System.out.print(pin);
    }

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.print("Please enter a user ID: ");
String entereduid = input.nextLine();
if(entereduid.equals(uid)){
System.out.print("Please enter a Pin #: "); 
String enteredpin = input.nextLine();
if(enteredpin.equals(pin)){
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("press 1 to check balance, 2 for a deposit, or 3 for a withdrawal: "); 
int ans = input.nextInt();
if(ans == 1){
System.out.print(balance);
output.println("The balance is now "+balance+"$.");
}
else if(ans == 2){
    System.out.print("Your current balance is: " + balance+". Please enter an amount to deposit: ");
    double dep = input.nextDouble();
    balance = balance + dep;
    System.out.print("You deposited "+dep+"$. Your new balance is: " + balance+"$.");
    output.println("The balance is now "+balance+"$.");
}
else if(ans == 3){
    System.out.print("Yor current balance is: "+balance+". Please enter an amount to withdrawl: ");
    double wit = input.nextDouble();
    balance = balance - wit;
    System.out.print("You withdrew "+wit+"$. Your new balance is: "+balance+"$.");
    output.println("The balance is now "+balance+"$.");

}}}}}
```

Comment: Think about using some methods which reflect your logic - write the logic out on paper first if necessary

Comment: A bit of indentation would help as well

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the pin from input as a String, but you read it from the file as an Integer; so Integer pin != String pin. Your pin is never recognized as correct so your program skips to the end.

Try `new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()` to read input as Integer.

So I'd change this line:

```
String enteredpin = input.nextLine();
```

to this:

```
Integer enteredpin = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Any particular reason that you're making a new `Scanner` instance? What's wrong with using the input instance instead?

Comment: @lane - you're right. The `new Scanner...` was just boilerplate - better to use the same Scanner instance if it's already been created. Will update

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to write the "person" object (i.e. an instance of BankRecord) to a file? As I don't know what methods there are in that class, I'll assume there is a suitable toString() override. I'll also assume that you're trying to write to your home directory.

```
        Path dir = Paths.get(URI.create("file:///"+System.getProperty("user.home")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"BankRecords.txt"));
        try (BufferedWriter bfr = Files.newBufferedWriter (dir, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
            String contents = person.toString();
            bfr.write(contents, 0, contents.length());
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
```